# Problem with listings-ext

Tags: errors, listings, lyx, ubuntu

I am using `listings-ext` on Ubuntu 11.10 (with LyX) and `listings.cfg` defines the style `colored-code` - which I also use in the LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage[style=colored-code]{listings-ext}
```

But whenever I try to compile the document - into DVI or PDF I get this:

```
 \newcommand
                {\lstdef}[3]{%
The following styles weren't loadable:
    ,colored-code$
This may cause errors in the sequel.
```

And a message saying "Package Listings Error: style colored-code undefined".

How can I fix this?

This is what listings.cfg has:

```
\lstdefinestyle{colored-code}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},%
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%
  identifierstyle=\color{black},%
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
  stringstyle=\color{teal},%
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{orange},%
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to edit your post and include `listings.cfg`? Or at least just the part where it defines `colored-code`?

Comment: Have done so now

Comment: Is your `listings.cfg` any different from what is posted in @someonr's "answer"?

Comment: Since you've solved your problem which stemmed from two different `listings.cfg`, I think this may be too localized.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=colored-code]{listings-ext}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

with the example `listings.cfg`:

```
\ProvidesFile{listings.cfg}%
  [2009/08/23 v1.0 listings configuration of listings-ext]

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\def\lstlanguagefiles{lstlang1.sty,lstlang2.sty,lstlang3.sty}
\lstset{defaultdialect=[ANSI]C,
        defaultdialect=[ISO]C++,
        defaultdialect=[95]Fortran,
        defaultdialect=Java,
        defaultdialect=[LaTeX]TeX,
        frame=tlb,
        resetmargins=false,
        }
\lstdefinestyle{colored-code}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!10},%
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%
  identifierstyle=\color{black},%
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
  stringstyle=\color{teal},%
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{orange},%
}
\lstdefinestyle{bw-code}{
  basicstyle=\small\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont,
  % instead of lmtt one should use ul9 (luximono) for boldface characters
  keywordstyle=\small\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\selectfont,
  commentstyle=\small\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{sl}\selectfont,
  stringstyle

=\small\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{it}\selectfont,
}
```

and it is all compiling without errors. I think your `listings.cfg` is wrong.

Comment: Yeah this is no real answer, but it would be too long for a comment, and should be able to help the question author to find the error.

Comment: I think I have the answer - seems to be a packaging error with Ubuntu: two conflicting listings.cfg files are supplied - one is an unadorned one, which doesn't have the colored-code style and one is supplied by listings-ext which does. I edited the unadorned one to add in the additional styles and it works now.

I will try to find out where the conflict is in Ubuntu (if that is where it comes from) and post a bug on their bugzilla.

Thanks for the help and time though - it's when you suggested I post the contents of the listings.cfg that I noticed their appeared to be two of them.

Comment: Bug duly filed [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-extra/+bug/911950]